# RSS feed for a given user's post?

Tags: users, rss

I know how to get the site's RSS feed - that `get_bloginfo('rss2_url')` but is there a way to get the same thing but only for a given user? Effectively the RSS feed of the posts listed on the author's page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function for getting an author's RSS feed URL is [`get_author_feed_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_feed_link/). You just need to pass it the user ID.